# Merge nested lists into groups in a list of tuple of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, neural-network, list-comprehension

I have a list of size 50000. say `a`. Each element is a tuple, say `b=a[0]`. Each tuple consists of 2 lists, say `c=b[0], d=b[1]`. 1st list i.e. `c` is of length 784 and the second i.e. `d` is of length 10. 
From this list, I need to extract the following:
Group first 10 elements of list `a`. From these 10 tuples, extract their first element (`c`) and put them in a matrix of size `784x10`. Also extract the second elements of the tuples and put them in another matrix of size `10x10`. Repeat this for every batch of 10 elements in list `a`.
Is this possible to do in a single line using list comprehension? Or do I have to write multiple for loops? Which method is efficient and best?
Note: It is okay if I get as a list or numpy.ndarray matrix.

**Additional Information**: I'm following [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) tutorial on neural networks which aims to design a neural network to recognize handwritten digits. MNIST database is used to train the network. The training data is in the above described format. I need to create a matrix of input_images and expected_output for every mini_batch.

Here is the code I've tried. I'm getting a list of size 50000. Its not getting split into mini_batches

```
f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
tr_d, va_d, te_d = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
f.close()
training_inputs = [numpy.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)

# training_data is a list of size 50000 as described above
n = len(training_data)  # n=50000
mini_batch_size = 10
mini_batch = [x[0] for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size) for x in training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]]
```

The `mnist.pkl.gz` is available [here](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/data/mnist.pkl.gz)

Comment: write it in multiple loops first, and then try to condense the parts one by one.

Comment: You "say" too much and show not enough code. Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [ask] and [edit] your post. Please prepare a [mcve] that represents the problem you have, add the code you wrote trying to solve it, add the expected and actual output and tell us what else you deem noteworty.

Comment: Thanks! I've added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my answer before you added the source and therefore it is purely based upon the first part where you write it out in words. It is therefore not very fail-safe in terms of changes in input size. If you read further in the book Anders Nielsen actually provides an implementation of his own.

My main answer is not a single line answer, as that would obfuscate what it does and I would advise you very much to write complex processes like this out so you have a better understanding of what actually happens. In my code I make a firstMatrix, which contains the c-elements in a matrix, and a secondMatrix, which contains the d-elements. I do this for every batch of 10, but didn't know what you want to do with the matrices afterwards so I just make them for every batch. If you want to group them or something, please say so and I will try to implement it.

```
for batch in np.array_split(a,10):
    firstMatrix = np.zeros(shape=(784,10))
    secondMatrix = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))
    for i in range(len(batch)):
        firstMatrix[:,i] = batch[i][0]
        secondMatrix[:,i] = batch[i][1]
```

If you really want a one-liner, here is one that makes an array of the firstMatrices and one for the secondMatrices:

```
firstMatrices = [np.array([batch[i][0] for i in range(len(batch))]).T for batch in np.array_split(a,10)]
secondMatrices = [np.array([batch[i][1] for i in range(len(batch))]).T for batch in np.array_split(a,10)]
```

Comment: I didn't know that he provides a solution later. Thanks. I thought there might be a single line solution using list comprehension which I'm not getting. Your advise to not write it as a single line does make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to be of help, just to show you it is possible I added a one-liner that should work(hard to test though for me), but for learning purposes I would advise the longer version :)

Comment: Thanks for the one liners. But I have a concern here. Here we loop twice and do array_split twice, right? But in the first approach you've provided, we loop only once. Won't this looping twice make the code inefficient as compared to the first one? Is it possible for a true one-liner i.e. with a looping only once?  

Also, there is bracket mismatch in the one liners. 1st line, there should be 2 parenthesis after batch, but there is only 1. Also, at the end there are 2 parenthesis where I think there should be only 1.

Comment: You were completey right with the brackets, I fixed them now. I guess these one-liners might be a tiny bit less efficient as you indeed do all iteration twice(there is less action per iteration so it's not twice as slow, but probably a little bit indeed). It is possible to put them together but that would mean the firstMatrix and secondMatrix would be zipped/in an array together or something and I wasn't sure you wanted that.